# time taken to integrate paypal into my website

Tags: php, joomla

I need to estimate a project, so i wanted to know, normally how much time it takes to integrate paypal to my website? am doing it for first time. i will be using jommla or drupal to build my site. Thanks.

Comment: I believe this depends on how experienced you are as a programmer. There are good instructions and it shouldn't take more than a couple of hours before it runs smoothly.

Comment: Hi thanks, i am a experienced php programmer. but this is first time i am asked to integrate paypal gateway. since i should give the project estimation, i wanted to know how much time it takes. so may be couple of days should be fine to understand and implement. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Only you can answer this since you know what the project is.

Comment: Its a site similar to shopping cart, where user select items and makes payment.

Comment: PayPal can be as simple as adding a buy button to a page, or as extensive as a full blown shopping experience. If you really want to know the inner workings of PayPal, you should read the docs and get a book on the topic. There's no way anyone can estimate your project. If it's a timing thing, and you're getting your feet wet I would suggest looking into third party shopping integrations like FoxyCart or PopCart.